# multi_query not working in mysqli to update realtime sphinx index via sphinxql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sphinx, sphinxql

We're using Sphinx realtime indexes and talking to them via PHP's mysqli driver. Single queries work fine, but we're trying to implement a batch update process using multi_query.

Queries look like this:

```
UPDATE rt SET rank = 1 WHERE id = 881523;
UPDATE rt SET rank = 2 WHERE id = 881727;
UPDATE rt ...
```

(this is after imploding with the semicolon, linebreaks added for ease of reading)

And the error we get is:

```
sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting $end near ';UPDATE rt SET rank = 2 WHERE id = 881727'
```

If I copy/paste the query into the mysql CLI client, no problem:

```
mysql> UPDATE rt SET rank = 1 WHERE id = 881523;UPDATE rt SET rank = 2 WHERE id = 882884;UPDATE rt SET rank = 3 WHERE id = 881727;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Here's the PHP code. `$conn` is an instance of the Connection class from http://foolcode.github.io/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/, but we're working with the underlying mysqli connection directly by using `$conn->getConnection()`:

```
$query = implode(';', $queries);
if($conn->getConnection()->multi_query($query)) {
        do { }
        while($conn->getConnection()->next_result());
}
if($conn->getConnection()->error) {
        error_log("query: " . $query);
        error_log($conn->getConnection()->error);
        die();
}
```

I've tried using the `multiQuery()` function from the SphinxQL Query Builder connection class with the same results.

The error message claiming the semicolon is unexpected seems the strangest part to me. If it wants $end, does that mean it's not supporting multiple queries? Why wouldn't it, if it's willing to take the same query via the mysql client?

```
$php -v
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Dec 29 2014 18:02:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I see that you use `implode()` but after imploding do you add a`;` at the end of `$query` to complete the SQL string?

Comment: I've tried with and without, no difference either way. I noticed that the sample code in a number of places didn't bother adding one at the end, so I believe it to be optional.

Comment: Have you considered using a prepared statement and simply iterating through the updates?  My guess is that you would get better performance this way, as the query does not need to be re-planned each time.

Comment: remember this is sphinx (despite this question being tagged with mysql) - sphinx doesnt support protocol prepared statements. (only client emulated ones)

Comment: Found this page: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-multi-queries.html. Seems to suggest that while it's supported for some types of queries, UPDATE is not one of them.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, you can answer your own question, just not accept it (I think)

Comment: looking into the API function you mentioned in the thread on the sphinx forums, and I'll update with the best approach I can come up with as an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at this time (version 2.2.7), the docs (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/sphinxql-multi-queries.html) indicate that multi query support is only for SELECT, SHOW WARNINGS, SHOW STATUS, and SHOW META queries. This explains why sphinx expects the end of the query and not a ';' for UPDATE queries.

Barry suggested to me on the sphinx forums (http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=13201) to use the sphinx API's UpdateAttributes (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-updateatttributes) function to handle the bulk updates. This worked very well. We're seeing 5k updates/second for two different indexes (same data indexed two different ways) on a single thread of our EC2 hardware (r3.xlarge, indexes on ephemeral SSD).

Answer (score 2):

the error message you are getting, is from the searchd server, because it **doesn't** expect multiple command conncateted with ;

The query works in the CLI, because the mysql **client** itself splits it upto into separate queries and sends them one-by-one to the server (see the delimiter option). 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/clients-and-utilities/mysql-client/delimiters-in-the-mysql-client/

mysqli, has a similar query function
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php
which is hardcoded to use ; apparently. Turns out that sphinx doesnt support it for UPDATE queries, only for queries - see comment on the main question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to make regarding mysqli's multi-query function. are you saying it's capable of splitting the queries itself and sending them one at a time or just reiterating that it can't give sphinx what it expects?

Comment: assuming sphinx can't handle the semicolon-separated queries, which does appear to be the case, is there a way of putting mysqli into a mode where it can quickly shoot over a bunch of queries for processing without waiting around for each round trip?  If we execute these queries one by one it takes a very long time.

Comment: I was mainly explainly WHY the CLI works. But also saying mysqli's multi_query SHOULD work. I can't explain why it doesnt work for you. But then again I've only ever used multi_query for doing multiple select statements, never multiple updates